# "Reaction to" or "reaction at"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Here's the context:

> So has gone the **reaction** of many **to** the news that Facebook is buying the mobile photo-sharing service Instagram[.]

Could "at" be used as well? I was taught that, when it comes to reactions, you should use "at": e.g. "I was surprised at the news", "I was shocked at his behavior", etc.

Comment: I don't think so. It is possible to say *react with*, *react like*, *react against* and *react to* but the preposition *at* is imho not possible.

Comment: Alright, so the verb "react" and its derivative "reaction" take the preposition "to", and that rules out "at". Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjectives **amazed** and **surprised** collocate with **at**, but the noun **reaction** doesn't. The only instances you can see the preposition **at** next to the word **reaction** is when a certain condition is mentioned at the time the reaction takes place, for example *"The reaction of the liquid at this temperature is..."*

Comment: That was crystal clear. Thank you so much, Irene. :-)